# TDD, how to tests two public methods if they use only one private method on nothing else?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Is it required to test 2 methods if they only use one private method with similar arguments?

For example I have some interface (contract):

```
public interface IInterface
{
   void Method1(arg1, arg2, arg3);
   void Method2(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

and implementation for this interface:

```
public class MyClass : IInterface
{
    public void Method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    {
        Method3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    }

    public void Method2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    {
        Method3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    }

    private void Method3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    {
        // handle data
    }
}
```

For example I have 3 tests for Method1, Is it required to copy-paste this tests for Method2 based on TDD/RGB rules

Comment: You need to unit test both the methods to make sure nothing is going wrong or to determine what is going wrong when you modify those methods. But the first question to ask is why a class have two methods with the same body.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Because I have interface, strong contract and in other interface implementations we have 2 different methods. This is exceptional case for this interface.

Comment: Yes... I realize that. It is in the best of the interest to cover all possible code of a class via unit test even if it's duplicate. Happy Coding...

Comment: The question itself is incorrect. In TDD, you don't write tests for already present methods, you write the test before the method even exists.
(and if you do, yes - you will end up having tests for all your methods. won't matter if they happen to share the same private method, that's just an impl detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you don't really want to go refactoring the callers of your class to use one simplified interface. And that might be reasonable if the places that are using this are widespread or in shared codebases that you can't refactor willy-nilly.

What I would do would be to turn this class into a facade for a cleaner interface. In other words, pull your private method into a new class with a concise interface. Then use the existing class in much the same way you already are but with an added dependency on the true implementation.

This has a couple of advantages:

1. You can start moving classes that depend on your original interface to the new implementation gradually. (Particularly if you deprecate these methods to alert other devs.) Eventually the facade can be removed entirely.
2. You can extensively unit test your new class.
3. You can write two very simple unit tests to verify that you're calling this dependency in the existing class. (No need to test every case anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

The **core** point of unit tests is to *verify* the *public* **contract** of your code under test.

In that sense - the first observation would be: in your example, both methods take the exact same arguments and do the exact same thing. Then the reasonable answer would be: you do not **need** Method1 and Method2 - you would make Method3 public and call that.

Assuming that your example is an over-simplification, you really have *two* choices:

- testing both public methods intensively
- focusing on Method1, and having some "ok, it works" tests for Method2

There are no golden rules here - you should step back and decided how *likely* it is for example that your implementation will ever change. But in that case, you would be doing TDD, right. This means in case you change Method2, you would *first* checkout the existing tests. And when you *then* find that they aren't sufficient - you can add more things.

Coming from there, I would go for option 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it required to copy-paste this tests for Method2 based on TDD/RGB rules

*Required* is a bit too strong; the TDD police are not going to come kick in your door.

But you are certainly coloring outside the lines.

If `MyClass.Method2` is really supposed to have the same behavior as `MyClass.Method1` in all interesting cases, then you ought to have a test that documents this property.

That test doesn't need to be a copy paste of the existing tests; it could be something like a data driven test.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void testMethodEquivalence () {
    val arg1 = TestContext.DataRow["arg1"]
    val arg2 = TestContext.DataRow["arg2"]
    val arg3 = TestContext.DataRow["arg3"]

    MyClass expected = new MyClass();
    MyClass sut = new MyClass();

    Assume.That(sut, Is.EqualTo(expected))

    expected.Method1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    sut.Method2(arg1, arg2, arg3)

    Assert.That(sut, Is.EqualTo(expected))
}
```

The point is that there should, somewhere, be enough constraints on the implementation of MyClass.Method2 that a fresh coder refactoring mercilessly will be alerted if any of the changes violate the class contract.